# Is there a directive that you can put in an HTML page to prevent or limit JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a directive that you can put in HTML that prevents all JavaScript from running for that page? The browser would see this metadata or directive and then enable or disable JavaScript based on that.

Let's say you want to create a HTML playground like Codepen, where the user can type in HTML markup and that is shown in another frame but you do not want them to run JavaScript or you want to limit it based on privileges.

I'd like a way to define a page by markup where I can disable Javascript, or set the same origin or set cross origin.

```
<html>
<head allowScript="none">
</head>
</html>

<html>
<head allowScript="same-domain">
</head>
</html>

<html>
<head allowScript="remote-domain">
</head>
</html>

<html>
<head allowScript="all">
</head>
</html>
```

That way I can have a page that allows not loading JavaScript, only JavaScript from the same site or only JavaScript offsite or allow same site and allow remote.

Does this makes sense? I know there are browser extensions that handle all of this but I want a page directive.

Comment: You should sanitize user inputs. Also run user code in iframe, so that he can not access outer page.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is "**Content-Security-Policy**" which can be set either via a HTTP response header or via META tags in your index.htm.

For example...

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src https:">
```

Content-Security-Policy is a large and rather complex topic that is best studied from the experts under...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy